# How to make button image to change color like normal text button?

Tags: ios

For normal text buttons, their color is assigned automatically by the system (the blue color) and is changed on different states.

However, for an image, the system doesn't color it for me and it is in the color of the original image.

For example, if I'm trying to make a browser, and used my back/forward image for buttons. It looks like this:

[image: browser]

The black doesn't look good, what I want is the blue color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also change the button type from `Custom` to `System` and the image will automatically be rendered with the `tint color` of the button. This is the default behavior.[image]

Comment: Cool! This is even better!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an easy fix:

Go to `Assets folder -- attribute inspector -- Render As`,
change it to "Template Image"

[image: config]

[image: screen]

Colored by system, perfect.